# last_day function not working in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

Database: DB2 v9.5.301.436

**Requirement:** I need to find number of days in a month.

**Code:**

```
select day(last_day(created)) 
from tablename
```

**Error:**

```
[Error Code: -440, SQL State: 42884]  DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, SQLERRMC=LAST_DAY;FUNCTION, DRIVER=3.57.82. 2) 
[Error Code: -727, SQL State: 56098]  DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, SQLERRMC=2;-440;42884;LAST_DAY|FUNCTION, DRIVER=3.57.82
```

I checked the DB2 documentation, Which shows above function is available.
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_lastday.html

Comment: I think you should check the manual for the DB2 version and platform that you actually have.

Answer (score 0):

the following works fine for me.

```
select day(last_day(current_timestamp)) 
from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

are you sure `created` is a date?

Comment: I checked this as well, It does not works for me. It might not be supported for DB2 v9.5.301.436 Which version you are using.

Comment: created is a timestamp

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked for me.

```
select day(date(date(created))-(day(date(created)) -1) days + 1 month -1 day)  as maxdate  , created  from customer  ;
```

**Note:** created column is a timestamfild

If created is a Date couln use below query.

```
select day(date(created)-(day(created) -1) days + 1 month -1 day)  as maxdate  , created  from customer  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

last_day where introduced in 9.7. You can roll your own like:

```
create function myfun.last_day(d date) 
returns date 
return (d + 1 month) - day(d + 1 month) days

with t(d) as ( 
    values date('2014-01-11') 
    union all 
    select d + 1 month 
    from t 
    where d<'2015-01-01'
) 
select d, myfun.last_day(d) from t
```